# Prove the series $\sum \frac{a_n}{a_n +1} $ is divergent.

Tags: real-analysis

This is assuming that $a_n \in (0,\infty)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ and there exists a set {$n \in \mathbb N|a_n \ge 1$} is not finite.

I've been going at this for a while now, trying different comparison tests and bending about inequalities and I simply cannot show it. Wondering if someone could help me. I did attempt a proof, it comes below:

$I_n =$ {$n \in N | a_n \ge 1$} then $I_n$ by definition is infinite and also countable hence $a_{I_n}$ is a subsequence of $a_n$. Notice $I_n \subseteq \mathbb N$.

Now I thought it was obvious that $0 \le \sum \frac{a_{I_n}}{1+a_{I_n}} \le \sum \frac{a_n}{1+ a_n}$ given by not only $I_n \subseteq \mathbb N$ but also $a_n > 0$ from the  definition of $a_n$. Then I said $0 \le \sum \frac{(1)_{n \in \mathbb N}}{(1)_{n \in \mathbb N} + 1} \le \sum \frac{a_{I_n}}{1+a_{I_n}}$ and claimed that we already knew $\sum \frac{(1)_{n \in \mathbb N}}{(1)_{n \in \mathbb N} + 1}$ was a divergent series. And by comparison test I concluded that $\sum \frac{a_n}{a_n +1} $ is divergent.

And please, if you can, let me know why my approach fails.

Comment: I think your attempt is the right idea. What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: Don't you reckon it's a bit hand wavey? Intuitively $0 \le \sum \frac{a_{I_n}}{1+a_{I_n}} \le \sum \frac{a_n}{1+ a_n}$ this isn't true for all of $n \in \mathbb N$ right? Because the new subsequence might grab bigger terms more quickly right?

Comment: Why did your classmate say that your intuition fails?

Comment: He suggested that $0 \le \sum \frac{a_{I_n}}{1+a_{I_n}} \le \sum \frac{a_n}{1+ a_n}$ might not always be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the set $L =$ {$n \in \mathbb N$ | $a_n \ge 1$}, by definition and hypothesis, this set is countable and infinite.

Suppose $l\in L$, we know $(a_{l})$ is a subsequence of $(a_n)$, moreover $\frac{a_{l}}{a_{l} + 1}$ is a subsequence of $\frac{a_n}{a_n + 1}$.

Clearly if $a_{l} \ge 1$ for all $l \in L$, then $0 \le \frac{1}{2} \le \frac{a_{l}}{a_{l} + a_{l}} \le \frac{a_{l}}{a_{l}+1}$ is also true for all $l \in L$.

So $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_{l}}{a_{l}+1} \ge \frac{1}{2} \ne 0$ by comparsion. Hence $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}$  $\frac{a_n}{a_n + 1} \ne 0$.

Thus $\sum \frac{a_n}{a_n + 1}$ cannot converge.

Answer (score 3):

$x\geq 1\implies \frac {x}{x+1}\geq \frac {1}{2}.$

$\sum_n \frac {a_n}{a_n+1}$ cannot converge unless $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {a_n}{a_n+1}=0.$

If $a_n\geq 1$ for infinitely many $n$ then $\frac {a_n}{a_n+1}\geq \frac {1}{2}$ for infinitely many $n.$

Comment: This portrays the idea very nicely. Using the contrapositive of "if $\sum a_n$ converges then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$", still would be more rigorous to show the last part using sub-sequences or something right? Since $a_n \ge 1$ for infinitely many $n$ doesn't exactly inform us of what the limit will be exactly.

Comment: I guess, you could just build the sub-sequence using those infinitely many $n$'s to highlight the existence of a sub-sequence that has a limit at $\frac{1}{2}$. But then the (original) sequence cannot have a limit at zero at all ever (since "if a sequence converges to $L$, then any subsequence converges to $L$") and sooo, it suggests that $\sum a_n$ diverges.

Comment: I now have a clear view. You're proof isn't perfectly complete due to just sheer explicitness. But it totally cleared up my view, so thank you!

Comment: What limit? Let $S(n)=\sum_{j=1}^n b_j. $ If $b_n\geq 1/2$ for infinitely many $n$ then $|S(n)-S(n-1)|>1/2$ for infinitely many $n$ so the sequence $(S(n))_{n\in \Bbb N}$ does not meet the Cauchy Criterion

Answer (score 1):

By your condition, there is a sub-sequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ such that $a_{n_k}\geq 1$.

(1)If this sub-sequence is bounded, so it has a convergent sub-sequence, W.L.G, also denoted by $\{a_{n_k}\}$, that is to say,$\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{n_k}=a\geq 1$. So $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{a_{n_k}}{a_{n_k}+1}=\frac{a}{1+a}>0.$$
(2)If this sub-sequence is unbounded, so it has a divergent sub-sequence, W.L.G, also denoted by $\{a_{n_k}\}$, that is to say,$\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{n_k}=\infty$. So $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{a_{n_k}}{a_{n_k}+1}=1.$$
In both above two cases, the series you given is divergent! Otherwise, we must have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n}+1}=0$.

Comment: What happens if the sub sequence is bounded but oscillating? The limit of this sequence wouldn't exist right?

Comment: Oh wait, any bounded sequence has a convergent sub-sequence, that's something I did actually learn (using a sun for a proof, such a phenomenal way of illustrating it actually).

Comment: It is so-called  Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to show why my proof doesn't suffice would you?

Comment: Your idea is right, but there is something to say. For example, you use that the function $\frac{x}{1+x},x\geq 1$ is increasing. And the inequality $ \sum \frac{(1)_{n \in \mathbb N}}{(1)_{n \in \mathbb N} + 1} \le \sum \frac{a_{I_n}}{1+a_{I_n}}$ should be $ \sum \frac{(1)_{n \in I_n}}{(1)_{n \in I_n} + 1} \le \sum \frac{a_{I_n}}{1+a_{I_n}}$.

Comment: Why would I need to use the fact that this function is increasing though? I only use the idea that there are simply more positive elements in the right hand side that are positive making the right side bigger.

Comment: @FlorianSuess You need $x/(x+1)$ is increasing so that $j\in I \colon a_j/(a_j+1) \geqslant 1/(1+1)$ hence $\sum_{j\in I} a_j/(a_j+1) \geqslant \sum_{j\in I} 1/2$ could hold.

Comment: But each $a_j$ is already greater than equal to 1 by selection of $n$ in $I$ since by definition if $n \in I$ $a_n \ge 1$

Comment: I say {$n \in N | a_n \ge 1$} = $I$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $\sum \frac{a_n}{a_n +1} $ is convergent. Then

$(*) \quad \frac{a_n}{a_n +1} \to 0$.

Hence there is $N$ such that $\frac{a_n}{a_n +1} \le 1/2$ for $n>N$. This gives $a_n \le 1$ for $n>N$. Therefore $(a_n)$ is bounded.

Now let $a$ be an accumulation point of $(a_n)$. Then there is a subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ with $a_{n_k} \to a$ as $k \to \infty$.

From $(*)$ we get $a=0$.

Thus the bounded sequence $(a_n)$ has exactly one accumulation point $a=0$. Therefore  $a_n \to 0$, which is a contradiction to $\{n \in \mathbb N|a_n \ge 1\}$ is not finite.

Hence $\sum \frac{a_n}{a_n +1} $ is divergent.